# What is the expected length of the linked list in the bucket h(x) where x is inserted?

Tags: hash, hashtable, probability

Imagine you have a weird hash function h: with probability 1/2 it maps a key uniformly at
random to one of the array slots in the range [0,m/4−1]; with probability 1/2, it maps a key
uniformly at random to one of the array slots in the range [m/4,m−1]. (Note: this assumption
is a replacement for the simple uniform hashing assumption.)
Assume chaining is used to resolve collisions, and that n items have been previously inserted
into the hash table. If a new item x is inserted, what is the expected length of the linked list in
the bucket h(x) where x is inserted?

1. (n/m)
2. (m/n)
3. (1/2)(n/m)
4. (1/2)(m/n)
5. (4/3)(n/m)
6. (3/4)(n/m)
7. (3/4)(m/n)
8. None of the above.

The answer is: (4/3)(n/m)

Can someone explain to me how do you calculate the expected value? My probability background is pretty weak so any explanation will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. of buckets in 1st half = (m/4 - 1) - (0) + 1 = m/4.
No. of buckets in 2nd half = (m - 1) - (m/4) + 1 = 3m/4.

Half of the n items would have gone into each side.
So n/2 items in 1st half to fit into m/4 buckets; n/2 items in 2nd half to fit into 3m/4 buckets.

E(length of linked list, i.e. “repeats” in 1st half) = n/2 / m/4 = 2(n/m).
E(length of linked list, i.e. “repeats” in 2nd half) = n/2 / 3m/4 = (2/3)(n/m).

x has an equal chance of being inserted into 1st half and 2nd half,
i.e. P(x in 1st half) = 1/2, P(x in 2nd half) = 1/2.

E(length of linked list in x’s bucket) = (1/2) (2(n/m)) + (1/2) ((2/3)(n/m) = n/m + (1/3)(n/m) = (4/3)(n/m).